# To use Active object or not?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, boost-asio, reactor, active-objects

The active object design pattern as I understand is tying up a (private/dedicated) thread life time with an object and making it work on independent data. From some of the documentation I read , the evolution of this kind of paradigm was because of two reasons , first , managing raw threads would be pain and second more threads contending for the shared resource doesn't scale well using mutex and locks.  while I agree with the first reason , I do not fully comprehend the second . Making an object active just makes the object independent but the problems like contention for lock/mutex is still there (as we still have shared queue/buffer), the object just delegated the sharing responsibility onto the message queue. The only advantage of this design pattern as i see is the case where I had to perform long asynch task on the shared object (now that i am just passing message to a shared queue , the threads no longer have to block for long on mutex/locks but they still will blocka and contend for publishing messages/task). Other than this case could someone tell more scenarios where this kind of design pattern will have other advantages.

The second question I have is (I just started digging around design patterns) , what is the conceptual difference  between , active object , reactor and proactor design pattern . How do you decide in which design pattern is more efficient and suits your requirements more. It would be really nice if someone can demonstrate certain examples showing how the three design patterns will behave and which one has comparative advantage/disadvantage in different scenarios.

I am kind of confused as I have used active object (which used shared thread-safe  buffer)  and boost::asio(Proactor) both to do similar kind of async stuff  , I would like to know if any one has more insights on applicability of different patterns when approaching a problem.

Answer (score 6):

The [ACE website](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/patterns-ace.html) has some very good papers on the [Active Object](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/Act-Obj.pdf), [Proactor](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/proactor.pdf) en [Reactor](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/reactor-siemens.pdf) design patterns. A short summary of their intents:

The **Active Object** design pattern decouples method execution
from method invocation to enhance concurrency and
simplify synchronized access to an object that resides in its
own thread of control. Also known as: Concurrent Object, Actor.

The **Proactor** pattern supports the demultiplexing and dispatching
of multiple event handlers, which are triggered by the completion
of asynchronous events. This pattern is heavily used in Boost.Asio.

The **Reactor** design pattern handles service requests that are delivered
concurrently to an application by one or more clients. Each service
in an application may consist of several methods and is represented by 
a separate event handler that is responsible for dispatching service-specific
requests. Also known as: Dispatcher, Notifier.

Comment: The link is no longer available. Can anyone provide a link to this ACE resource page?

Answer (score 0):

[ACE working URL](https://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/%7Eschmidt/patterns-ace.html) with the details on Active Objects, Proactor and Reactor design patterns migrated to another university web-hosting.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35482811)